# Promise returns empty value

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm learning how to use promises to do async tasks.

I'm struggling with a problem that I can't figure it and after searching and reading other posts here I'm don't know how fix it.

```
function processStuff(things) {
    var result = {};
    var pictures = checkPictures(data);

    if (pictures.length > 0) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
            var promisesArray = [];
            pictures.forEach(function(picture) {
                promisesArray.push(getBase64(picture));
            });

            Promise.all(promisesArray).then(function(processedPictures) {
                result = getOtherSutff(things);
                var insertedElements = Object.keys(result).length;
                for (var index = 0; index < processedPictures.length; index++) {
                    var item = processedPictures[index];
                    result['thingId-' + (++insertedElements).toString()] = item;
                }
            });
            resolve(result); (1)
        });
    } else {
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
            result = getOtherSutff(things);
            resolve(result);
        });
    }
}
```

When I debug the code, I can see that in (1) the variable it's filled with the data but when I call the function and try to use the data:

```
...........
processStuff(things).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result)
});
..........
```

I see on the terminal: `{}`.

Where is my mistake or what I'm doing wrong?

Regards.

Comment: You're calling `resolve` outside the `then` of `Promise.all()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move your `resolve(result)` inside your `Promise.all` callback:

```
   Promise.all(promisesArray).then(function(processedPictures) {
        result = getOtherSutff(things);
        var insertedElements = Object.keys(result).length;
        for (var index = 0; index < processedPictures.length; index++) {
            var item = processedPictures[index];
            result['thingId-' + (++insertedElements).toString()] = item;
        }
        resolve(result); // result is available here
    });
    resolve(result); // result has not been set here
```

Comment: what if get rid of `new Promise()` at all and just `return Promise.all(...).then(...)` instead?

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I thought that you have to resolve the "parent" promise, not the "children". 'return new Promise...' do not waits until 'Promise.all...' gets resolved? That's why I put the resolve outside :/